# WebSphere custom password encryption - implementation class

Tags: websphere

**I followed the steps here:**

http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_7.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.iseries.doc/info/iseriesnd/ae/tsec_plugpoint_custpass_encrypt.html

**In particular, implementing the interface given here:**

http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_7.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.iseries.doc/info/iseriesnd/ae/csec_plugpoint_custpass_encrypt.html

Can anyone post sample implementation class for custom password encryption?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, but it's worth a read if you haven't done so, and it gives a little additional information: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/1212_col_lansche/1212_col_lansche.html

Answer (score 1):

bala_1980.  I uploaded my sample and notes when I tried it out.  A silly sample but it worked very well for me.  Hope it saves your time.  https://github.com/una-tapa/WebSphere-Classic-Custom-encoding-sample